# Error in pygame, cannot find object 'ship'

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings

from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")



    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()
    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right=True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = False
    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   
    ai = AlienInvasion()

    ai.run_game()
```

Error: getting an `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'AlienInvasion' object has no attribute 'ship'
```

I am importing the class ship which is:

```
import pygame

class Ship:

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        self.moving_right = False

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.x += 1


    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong!

Comment: It should only be ```ship.blitme()```. ```self``` represents the instance. Python thinks that ```AlienInvasion``` has an attribute: ```ship```. But it doesn't

Comment: Likely you have to create an instance of `Ship` in the constructor (in `AlienInvasion.__init__`): `self.ship = Ship(self)`

Comment: @Sujay thank you for replying, it was my bad that I didn't add  'self.ship = Ship(self)' after   pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

Answer (score 1):

Your `AlienInvasion.__init__` method needs to create a ship attribute. You want to add the line:

```
self.ship = Ship(self)
```

You have already created settings this way. You need to add another attribute.